# Accessing Shadow copy of drive with C#

Tags: c#, file-io, drive, shadow-copy

We have to write a file in one drive (L) which is the shadow copy of the C drive. We tried with normal like below.

```
string datFile = "L:\\DATA\\ABC.DAT";

string message = "test";
        try
        {

            using (StreamWriter writerAppend = new StreamWriter(datFile, true))
            {
                writerAppend.WriteLine(message);


            }


        }
```

But it is giving error

> System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'L:\DATA\ABC.DAT

Please help if there is any specific way to access it.

Comment: [Shadow copy volumes are read-only.](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc785914%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

Comment: @DarkFalcon si that then the normal error message for trying to access the non writeable shadow volume? (I would expect a different IO error tbh oO)

Comment: No, probably not, but it is hard to say. I've never tried it.

Comment: Same here and in addition didnt even know till this questoin that microsoft offers such a feature for a few operating systems. 

For the originalposter: Are you sure that L:\DATA exists ? If so can you try the same code on a non shadow copy volume ? (it could be that as dark falcon mentioned them being read only that the read only part causes the problem, although like I mentioned I would expect a different error message there with a non shadow copy drive it could be made sure that its really coming from the shadow copy and not some different reason)

Comment: Is there a folder `Data` on disk `L:` already? `StreamWriter` will create file no prob, but it **can't** create directory.

Comment: @Thomas yes the DATA exists. I can see those folder while I am remotely connecting. Also I notice one difference is that programmatically when I tried to access the drives in it, it is not listing out the L drive. Strange. But I can see it in my computer as Local Dist.